# DB2 Temporary Table within Function

Tags: sql, db2, db2-9.7

I have got simple functions to work in DB2 but I am unable to get any functions to work which declare a global temporary table. I am aware the DB2 version and platform is vastly different but I thought this should be possible as it worked for [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127647/udtf-returning-a-table-on-db2-v5r4-with-dynamic-sql).

```
CREATE FUNCTION FuncTest1 ()
    RETURNS TABLE
    (
        USE_NAME VARCHAR(48),
        USE_PARTNER_LINK FLOAT
    )
        LANGUAGE SQL
        MODIFIES SQL DATA
        DETERMINISTIC
        BEGIN
        DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE USE_TRUNC
        (
           USE_NAME VARCHAR(48) NULL,
           USE_PARTNER_LINK FLOAT NULL
        );
        INSERT INTO SESSION.USE_TRUNC
            (USE_NAME,USE_PARTNER_LINK)
        SELECT USE_NAME,USE_PARTNER_LINK FROM F_USERS;
        RETURN
        SELECT USE_NAME,USE_PARTNER_LINK FROM F_USERS;
        END
```

The errors vary widely as I try different things but this is the current output:

```
An unexpected token "USE_NAME" was found following " 
  RETURN 
  SELECT".  Expected tokens may include:  "(".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78
```

Added [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=dd20b87a45d5d946920f4655f31b7a63)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CREATE FUNCTION (SQL scalar, table, or row) statement, v9.7](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html):

> `-|                    (3)|
>   '-MODIFIES SQL DATA-----'
>   ...
>   |--+-RETURN----------------------+------------------------------|
>   |                         (5) |
>   +-Compound SQL (compiled)-----+
>   '-Compound SQL (inlined)------'`
>    ...
>   3. Valid if RETURNS specifies a table (that is, TABLE column-list). Also valid if RETURNS specifies a scalar result and the
>   SQL-function-body is a compound SQL (compiled) statement.
>   ...
>   5. The compound SQL (compiled) statement is supported only for an SQL-function-body in an SQL scalar function definition. **It is not
>   supported for SQL table function definitions**.

[CREATE FUNCTION (SQL scalar, table, or row) statement, v11.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html):

> `-|                   (4) |
>   '-MODIFIES SQL DATA-----'`
>   ...
>   4. Valid only for compiled scalar function definition and an **inlined table function definition**.

You can't use `MODIFIED SQL DATA` with `Compound SQL (compiled)` (`BEGIN ... END`) for a table function. And `DECLARE GTT` statement is not supported by `Compound SQL (inlined)` (`BEGIN ATOMIC ... END`).
So, rewrite your table function not using Declared GTTs & INSERTs. Or try [Created GTT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053719.html), but create them beforehand (not in the function body).

## As for your case

You may use a single `SELECT` statement with `Common Table Expression`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ...
...
RETURN
WITH 
SESSION_ALLREFERRALS AS 
(
SELECT
    REF.AL_NO AS AL_NO,        
    ENQ.E_KEY AS R_KEY,
    APP.A_2ND_NAME AS R_TRADING_NAME,
    CASE WHEN DOC1.DT_NAME is null THEN 'NONE' ELSE DOC1.DT_NAME END AS R_DROP1,
    REF.AL_DATE AS R_DATE,
    CASE WHEN DOC2.DT_NAME is null THEN 'Incomplete' ELSE DOC2.DT_NAME END AS R_DROP2,
    CAST(ENQ2.E_TOOLCOMM1 AS VARCHAR(48)) AS R_COMM1
FROM
    F_ENQUIRY ENQ INNER JOIN 
        F_APPLICANT_LINK REF ON REF.AL_KEY1 = ENQ.E_KEY INNER JOIN 
        F_APPLICANT APP ON APP.A_KEY = REF.AL_KEY2 AND REF.AL_TYPE1 = 2 AND REF.AL_TYPE2 = 1 LEFT JOIN 
        F_DOC_TYPES DOC1 ON DOC1.DT_NO = REF.AL_DROP1 LEFT JOIN 
        F_DOC_TYPES DOC2 ON DOC2.DT_NO = REF.AL_DROP2 INNER JOIN 
        F_ENQUIRY ENQ2 ON ENQ2.E_KEY = REF.AL_ENQ_LINK
WHERE
    ENQ.E_PRIORITY_LINK = 204 AND   
    ENQ.E_JOB_TYPE_LINK = 0
)
, 
SESSION_REFERRAL1 AS 
(
SELECT 
    MIN(AL_NO) AL_NO, 
    R_KEY
    FROM 
    SESSION_ALLREFERRALS 
    GROUP BY R_KEY
)
,
SESSION_REFERRAL2 AS 
(
SELECT 
    MIN(AL_NO) AL_NO, 
    R_KEY 
FROM 
    SESSION_ALLREFERRALS a2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SESSION_REFERRAL1 R1 WHERE r1.AL_NO = a2.AL_NO fetch first 1 rows only)
GROUP BY 
    R_KEY
)
,
SESSION_REFERRAL3 AS 
(
SELECT 
    MIN(AL_NO) AL_NO, 
    R_KEY 
FROM 
    SESSION_ALLREFERRALS A3
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SESSION_REFERRAL1 R1 WHERE R1.AL_NO = A3.AL_NO fetch first 1 rows only) AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SESSION_REFERRAL2 R2 WHERE R2.AL_NO = A3.AL_NO fetch first 1 rows only)
GROUP BY 
    R_KEY
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    SESSION_REFERRAL1 R1 INNER JOIN
    SESSION_ALLREFERRALS A ON A.R_KEY = R1.R_KEY AND R1.AL_NO = A.AL_NO LEFT JOIN
    SESSION_REFERRAL2 R2 ON R2.R_KEY = R1.R_KEY LEFT JOIN
    SESSION_ALLREFERRALS A2 ON A2.R_KEY = R2.R_KEY AND R2.AL_NO = A2.AL_NO LEFT JOIN 
    SESSION_REFERRAL3 R3 ON R3.R_KEY = R1.R_KEY LEFT JOIN
    SESSION_ALLREFERRALS A3 ON A3.R_KEY = R3.R_KEY AND R3.AL_NO = A3.AL_NO
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is a simplified form of what I'm trying to create (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w692rHjMm4/) so I don't know how I would rewrite with no declares or inserts. My current solution will be to create this as a procedure to make the temp tables and insert the data, then call it in a function then return the select statement. Is there a more sensible way?

Comment: See the example of your function for your mentioned case at the link above.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. I have recreated it in a fiddle and it works, but I get another useless 'An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  ".E_JOB_TYPE_LINK = 0"' error on my test server. Are there any 9.7 specific issues you can think of?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein the v10.1 and higher Db2-LUW docs changed the note (5) regarding Compound SQL(compiled) statement usage, and now includes the text **"d) Not supported when defining a table function in a partitioned database environment."**. While a non-partitioned database seems to support Compound-SQL(compiled) as the body of a table function, Db2 v11.1 still throws -526 if an SQL table function tries to `return select ... from dgtt`

Comment: I found it, 9.7 just didn't like a few of the semicolons. Created as a view which will be perfect.

Comment: @mao I didn't suggest to use `DGTT`s in the function body. I mentioned `CGTT`s...

Comment: @corky My fault - I forgot to remove the `;` symbol from the text here: `ENQ.E_JOB_TYPE_LINK = 0;`. I've updated the example...

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simpler way to write that function

```
CREATE FUNCTION FuncTest1 ()
RETURNS TABLE
(
    USE_NAME VARCHAR(48),
    USE_PARTNER_LINK FLOAT
)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    RETURN  SELECT USE_NAME,USE_PARTNER_LINK FROM F_USERS;
```

Comment: I got that working but I needed temporary tables, which eventually I hoped to select from.